# Why am I seeing “failed to load the given url”?

Tags: php, image-loading

I've some images in the server. But the images are not shown. I've used the following code.

```
$baseUrl = "http://gkill7777.net";
<img width="600" src="<?php '.$baseUrl.' ?>/test/test_pssg/images<?php echo $recPsgQuesTest1->pssg; ?>" />`
```

Is it a server problem or my coding problem? The code is running swiftly on my local server…

Comment: Please, add some more information about what you want to do.
$baseUrl = "http://gkill7777.net/test/test_pssg/imagespssg";

Comment: It could be anything, use echo $baseUrl as someone suggested, also make sure all the cases match (often live servers are case sensitive). I usually right click the missing image and open in new window, that what way you can see where it's looking for the image. Compare it with the image location and see if they match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
<img width="600" src="<?php '.$baseUrl.' ?>/test/test_pssg/images<?php echo $recPsgQuesTest1->pssg; ?>" />
```

change

```
<?php '.$baseUrl.' ?>
```

To

```
<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>
```